# MVC 5 Error when getting user details to populate in text box with an on-click

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having an eternal 500 error message when I click on the button to get the users information to populate in the text-boxes. I have tried multiple things to figure it out but I am very much stumped at this point any help would be appreciated.

[image]

UserController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SampleMvc.Domain;
using SampleMvc.Models;
using SampleMvc.Repository;

namespace SampleMvc.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public UserController()
        {
            _userRepository = new UserRepository();
        }

        public UserController(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        public ActionResult UserDetails()
        {
            UserModel model = new UserModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        public JsonResult PopulateDetails(UserModel model)
        {
            UserResultModel userResultModel = new UserResultModel();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserId))
            {
                userResultModel.Message = "UserId can not be blank";
                return Json(userResultModel);
            }

            User user = _userRepository.GetUser(model.UserId);

            if (user == null)
            {
                userResultModel.Message = String.Format("No UserId found for {0}", model.UserId);
                return Json(userResultModel);
            }
            userResultModel.LastName = user.LastName;
            userResultModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            userResultModel.Message = String.Empty; //success message is empty in this case

            return Json(userResultModel);
        }
    }

    public class UserResultModel
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UserModel.cs

```
namespace SampleMvc.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UserDetails.Cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserDetails";
}

<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript">

    function populateUserDetails() {
        var user = {};
        user.UserId = $("#UserId").val();
        $.getJSON("PopulateDetails", user, updateFields);
        //$.post("PopulateDetails", user, updateFields, 'json');
    };

    updateFields = function (data) {
        $("#LastName").val(data.LastName);
        $("#FirstName").val(data.FirstName);
        $("#Message").html(data.Message);
    };
</script>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>User Details</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="UserId">UserId:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("UserId")
                <input type="button" id="GetUser" value="Populate User Details" onclick='populateUserDetails()' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="LastName">LastName:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("LastName")
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="FirstName">FirstName:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("FirstName")
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Domain folder User.cs

```
namespace SampleMvc.Domain
{
    public class User
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Repository folder IUserRepository.cs

```
using SampleMvc.Domain;

namespace SampleMvc.Repository
{
    public interface IUserRepository
    {
        User GetUser(string userId);
    }
}
```

Repository Folder UserRepository.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using SampleMvc.Domain;

namespace SampleMvc.Repository
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        #region IUserRepository Members

        public User GetUser(string userId)
        {
            return Database.Users.Where(user => user.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Database
    {
        public static List<User> Users = new List<User>
                                             {
                                                 new User
                                                     {
                                                         UserId = "john_doe",
                                                         LastName = "Doe",
                                                         FirstName = "John",
                                                         Age = 25
                                                     },
                                                 new User
                                                     {
                                                         UserId = "user2",
                                                         LastName = "SomeLastName",
                                                         FirstName = "SomeFirstNAme",
                                                         Age = 28
                                                     },
                                             };
    }
}
```

The change for the fix thanks to the answer

```
 public JsonResult PopulateDetails(UserModel model)
        {
            UserResultModel userResultModel = new UserResultModel();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserId))
            {
                userResultModel.Message = "UserId can not be blank";
                return Json(userResultModel,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            User user = _userRepository.GetUser(model.UserId);

            if (user == null)
            {
                userResultModel.Message = String.Format("No UserId found for {0}", model.UserId);
                return Json(userResultModel,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            userResultModel.LastName = user.LastName;
            userResultModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            userResultModel.Message = String.Empty; //success message is empty in this case

            return Json(userResultModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return JSON data from a GET action method like that. That is the reason you are getting a 500 error.

Whenever you try to return Json data from a GET Action method, you need to pass `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as the second parameter. If you do not pass any value for this param, It will take the default value which is `DenyGet` and you will get an error.

So pass `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in your JSON method.

```
public JsonResult PopulateDetails(UserModel model)
{
   var userResultModel = new UserResultModel();
   userResultModel.FirstName = "Hard coded for demo";
   return Json(userResultModel ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: That might be some other error. Just open the url in a new browser. You might be able to see the url if you open the network tab of your browser.

Comment: oh wait got it fixed

Comment: Now I just have to figure how to change the code out to link to database instead of hard-coded